# Convert string to byte array with error trap

Tags: arrays, powershell, byte

Given a string such as `0x33,0x32,0xff` I want to convert to a byte array, so I can write to a Registry property of type Reg_Binary.
I have this

```
$string = '0x33,0x32,0xff'
$array = $string -split ','
[byte[]]$hex = [byte[]]$array
$hex.GetType()
```

Which works when the string is valid, and also when the string is junk, such as `0x33,0x32,0xzz`. I really expected `[byte[]]$array` to throw an exception, and I am wondering why it didn't? And, is there a graceful way to test the string or array? Or am I going to need to validate each item in the array myself, with a RegEx perhaps? I do have control over the format of the string, but given the way a Reg_Binary looks in RegEdit I figured this format was a decent option that was easy(wish) to create based on something actually found in the registry, while also making the format very clearly not a simple string. But if there is a much better solution to the overall problem, that uses a different string format, I am all ears.

EDIT: Interestingly, I do get an exception with `[byte[]](0x33,0x32,0xzz)`, so it seems the issue is when I cast the string, and in parentheses or not, it throws no error. I feel like this is one of those "Powershell trying to be helpful and screwing everything up" moments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Your code *does* trigger a statement-terminating error if any of the `,`-separated tokens cannot converted to a `[byte]` value.
- If it doesn't, the implication is that `$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'` is in effect, or there is a `try` / `catch` or `trap` handler in place that silently ignores errors.

Either way, you can use a `try` / `catch` statement to catch the error, and the error message will point out the (first) token that cannot be coerced to `[byte]`:

```bash
try {
  # Note: No strict need to also have a [byte[]] cast on the RHS.
  [byte[]] $byteArray = '0x33,0x32,0xzz' -split ','
}
catch {
  # Sample error handling.
  Write-Warning $_
}
```

Output:

```bash
WARNING: Cannot convert value "0xzz" to type "System.Byte". Error:
         "Could not find any recognizable digits."
```

Comment: Interesting. Preference was a simple Continue, not silently continue, so outside of a Try/Catch it just rolls on. But I should have wrapped it in a try/catch first thing. Actual code will definitely use try/catch.

Comment: @Gordon, it definitely should report an error by default. Try in a pristine session as follows: `powershell -NoProfile -Command "[byte[]] ('0x33,0x32,0xzz' -split ',')"` - you should see an error.

Comment: Definitely something buggy with the ISE for me. Seems like the value of the variable is locked after one run, so when I tested once with good data, then changed to bad data and reran, I got no error. Also posted about a probably related issue here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76090062/write-host-string-literal-weirdness).